# How to improve an estimator that is already unbiased?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, exponential-distribution, rao-blackwell

[image]

I am solving a two part problem where the second part of the problem is to improve on the estimator in the first using the Rao-Blackwell theorem. In this case, the sufficient statistic is just Y itself, the minimum of the n random variables. I understand that to improve the estimator you write out the conditional expectation given the sufficient statistic, but intuitively to me it seems like the sufficient statistic was part of the first part of the problem. Whenever I write out the conditional expectation I get the same as the first!

Comment: No, min{X_1,...,X_n} is not a sufficient statistic. When you write down the joint density of {X_1,...,X_n} as an exponential family (see Lehman & Casella, for example), you will see that (X_1 + ... + X_n) is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: $Y$ is a sufficient statistic when observing $Y$ but not when observing the whole sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. (Please add the `self-study` tag.)